# In django user model what does @propery represents

Tags: python, django

Below is the code from sample custom user model with staff field. I am new to Django framework. Can anyone explain what is the difference between @propery and without specifying it?
It's not making sense with or without it in terms of accessing it.
Does @propery provides any additional functionality like setting the fields values.
Correct me if I am wrong

```
@property
def is_staff(self):
    "Is the user a member of staff?"
    return self.staff

def is_staff(self):
    "Is the user a member of staff?"
    return self.staff
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python, not only in Django, [`property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) is a decorator that could be used to decorate a method in order to compute some value.

As stated in the docs about `property`:

> A typical use is to define a managed attribute

`is_staff` with the `property` decorator is a value you can access in your instance as follows

```
instance.is_staff
```

The `@property` decorator turns the `is_staff()` method into a *“getter”* for a read-only attribute with the same name.

`is_staff` without the `property` decorator is a method you can call in your instance as follows:

```
instance.is_staff()
```

Answer (score 0):

`@property` is a built-in for python. It is a great way to add properties to a class that require some sort of evaluation and it isn't just a Django concept. In this example it doesn't seem like `@property` is being used as I would expect. In this example it is only returning the staff property. The `@property` decorator allows you to access `is_staff` as property of the instance. Here is an example.

```
class Num:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    @property
    def is_even(self):
        return self.x % 2 == 0

a = Num(2)
a.is_even #returns True
```